# Adding elements to a dictionary of sets

Tags: python

I have a dictionary `d` of sets. When adding an element under some key `key` I consider the two cases `key in d` and `not key in d`:

```
from random import randint

for i in range(1000):
    key = randint(0, 100)

    if key in d:
        d[key] |= set([randint(0, 10)])
    else:
        d[key] = set([randint(0, 10])
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Can I unify the two cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like using a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), which is a kind of dictionary which creates a default object when you refer to a key which isn't yet defined:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> 
>>> for i in range(10):
...     el = randint(0, 5)
...     d[el].add(randint(0,10))
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {0: set([2]), 1: set([7]), 2: set([8, 9, 5, 7]), 
3: set([1]), 4: set([1, 3, 4])})
>>> d[0]
set([2])
>>> d[2]
set([8, 9, 5, 7])
```

Comment: Nice! This is pretty much want I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)`s: `from collections import defaultdict`

A `defaultdict` takes a "`default factory`" parameter. Basically, it lets you set a default value for keys that haven't been "initialized" yet.

So in your example, you wouldn't have to do the `if el in d` check, if `d` is a `defaultdict`. While that check would still return `False`, doing `d[el] |= set([randint(0, 10)])` would essentially result in the following, if `el` wasn't already in `d`:

```
d[el] = set([])
d[el] |= set([randint(0, 10)])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The first part of the suggestion is good, but he wouldnt even need to create another set and add it that way. You can just simply call the add() method and save the overhead.

Comment: I only meant that as an example of what is going on "under the hood". I don't recommend that he do that.