# dynamically create and search a dictionary of IPs with their seen timestamps

Tags: python, search, dictionary, dynamic, set

beginner python user here

I read a logfile with IP adresses and timestamps and want to create a list with each IP showing at what instant the IP was seen.
So one IP can have multiple timestamps.
I think a dictionary of sets would do the job, but I cannot figure out how to create this dynamically.

example data

```
10.1.1.10 1441110489
10.1.1.15 1441110490
10.1.1.10 1441110491
10.1.1.11 1441110492
10.1.1.10 1441110492
10.1.1.11 1441110493
```

should result in

```
10.1.1.10 1441110489,1441110491,1441110492
10.1.1.11 1441110492,1441110493
10.1.1.15 1441110490
```

this part is self-answered below.

Bonus problem: later I want to search in this data for a timestamp but with a little time window. So not an exact match. I guess I need to iterate over all the data for my search? (I can post this as a separate question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following approach:

```
import collections

def get_ip_address(start_time, end_time):
    global d_entries

    matching_ip = set()
    for k, v in d_entries.items():
        for timestamp in v:
            if start_time <= timestamp <= end_time:
                matching_ip.add(k)

    return matching_ip

ip_list = [
"10.1.1.10 1441110489",
"10.1.1.15 1441110490",
"10.1.1.10 1441110491",
"10.1.1.11 1441110492",
"10.1.1.10 1441110492",
"10.1.1.11 1441110493"]

d_entries = collections.defaultdict(list)

for ip_entry in ip_list:
    ip, timestamp = ip_entry.split(" ")
    d_entries[ip].append(int(timestamp))

print get_ip_address(1441110490, 1441110492)
```

This would display 3 matches as follows:

```
set(['10.1.1.11', '10.1.1.10', '10.1.1.15'])
```

Answer (score 3):

From [Adding elements to a dictionary of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449076/adding-elements-to-a-dictionary-of-sets) I made this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> iplist=defaultdict(set)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.10"].add(1441110489)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.15"].add(1441110490)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.10"].add(1441110491)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.11"].add(1441110492)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.10"].add(1441110492)
>>> iplist["10.1.1.11"].add(1441110493)
>>> iplist
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'10.1.1.11': set([1441110492, 1441110493]), '10.1.1.10': set([1441110489, 1441110491, 1441110492]), '10.1.1.15': set([1441110490])})
```